# get ArrayList from Json

Tags: java, android, json

I have a Json response from REST API like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "leagues": [
      {
        "identifier": "8e7fa444c4b60383727fb61fcc6aa387",
        "league_slug": "bundesliga",
        "name": "Bundesliga",
        "nation": "Germany",
        "level": "1",
        "federation": "UEFA"
      },
      {
        "identifier": "726a53a8c50d6c7a66fe0ab16bdf9bb1",
        "league_slug": "premier-league",
        "name": "Premier League",
        "nation": "England",
        "level": "1",
        "federation": "UEFA"
      },
      {
        "identifier": "bc425f51d5ee924580c35c38da138de8",
        "league_slug": "serie-a",
        "name": "Serie A",
        "nation": "Italy",
        "level": "1",
        "federation": "UEFA"
      }
    ],
    "statusCode": "200",
    "errorCode": "0",
    "statusReason": "OK"
  }
}
```

I want to get List of Leagues from this Json
now I have "data" hashmap but I can't get array of hashMaps of Leagues.
I don't want to convert it to any data type, I only want `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>`

please help me to get this information using `Gson` or `JSONObject`

Comment: the problem is "data" hashmap is `Map<String, Object>` 
so I cant get the value (ArrayList) as it's Object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse this string using

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
```

When you can retrive any data you want:

```
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray leagues = data.getJSONArray("leagues");
```

iterate like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < leagues.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject childJSONObject = leagues.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: how can I access cascading objects like "leagues" ?